# assert error in symfony/translations when dumping translations

Tags: symfony, php-8.1, symfony6

I have recently updated my project from symfony 6.1 to symfony 6.2 and I'm experiencing issue while dumping translations

commend that I use:
`bin/console translation:extract pl --force --format=yaml`
results in:
[image: dump translation console error]

exception trace points to
`vendor/nikic/php-parser/lib/PhpParser/Node/Expr/CallLike.php:36`

I've already updated all packages, especially `symfont/translation` to version `6.2.*`

For now, only downgrading symfony back to 6.1 solves this for me.

Comment: I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in symfony 6.2.2. You can update your project and try again.

It has been resolved in my projects.

```
composer update "symfony/*"
```